# Shift each div having same class to a new position on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is part of my code. Whenever I click on a div I want some things to happen.
There is some problem with the function xyz as alert("good") is not showing.

```
$("#subarea").click(function(e)
  {
     $('.pointer').removeClass("pointer").addClass("hiddenpointer");
     $('.visible').css('z-index','1');   
     $('.hiddenimg').css('z-index','2'); 
     $('#closeit').css('z-index','4');
     $('.popupbox').css('display','none');
     alert("hey");
     xyz();
     alert("good");

   });
```

There are some links in my code with class "pointer1". I want to shift them to a new position on click of a mouse for which I am using this function.

```
function xyz()
{
     alert("idiot");
     var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('pointer1');
     for (var i = 0;i < elem.length; i++)
     {
     top1=elem[i].css('top');
     alert(top1);
     left1=elem[i].css('left');
     top1=top1*4;
     left1=left*5/3;
     elem[i].css({left:left1,top:top1}).show();
     }

}
```

Comment: Recreate the problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Launch in IE, press F12 and look for javascript errors and tell us what error is thrown. In future use developer tools on all browsers, they are indispensable if you are really serious about developing web applications.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pooja8bhatt/pgBcW/

Comment: Whenever i click on the transparent div i want some of my anchors to get invisible which is happening and some to move to a new position which is not working.

Comment: i have added alert msgs just to see till where the code working.

Comment: I didn't like it when it said "hey idiot"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pgBcW/34/ , your code contained many errors

1. Used wrong variable names.
2. Did not use var while initializing variables.
3. Used elem[i] instead of $(elem[i]).
4. Used show() instead of animate(). Its already showing, so you need to use animate() as its positioning attributes are changing.
5. getElementByClassName function does not exist in javascript, altered it and used $(".pointer1").

NOTE: Be careful next time while coding.